# Keras 0.3 Documentation

Tags: documentation, keras

I can't seem to find Keras 0.3 documentation anywhere. At Keras.io the documentation is for the newer version and there don't seem to be any links to older versions of the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation found @ a fork of Keras 0.3.3:

https://github.com/cartopy/keras-0.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, here is a site which hosts several Keras versioned API docs online.

https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/